# How to create a button as a subview of MPMoviePlayerController?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6, custom-controls, mpmovieplayercontroller

I am trying to add a custom play button but can't put it in front of the video. here is my code.

```
- (IBAction)playMovie:(UIButton *)sender {


    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:urlStr.text];
    self.movie = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];
    self.movie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;


    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,self.view.frame.size.width,self.view.frame.size.height)];
    button.backgroundColor=[UIColor yellowColor];
    [button setTitle:@"Normal State Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    [movie.view addSubview:button];

    self.movie.shouldAutoplay = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:self.movie.view];
    [self.movie setFullscreen:YES animated:NO];
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is what you are looking for. Here is simple example.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{
   [super viewDidLoad];
   // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

   url=[NSURL URLWithString:@"https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t50.2886-16/11179443_819874424728492_389701720_n.mp4"];

   movPlayer=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] init];
   [movPlayer setContentURL:url];
   [movPlayer setMovieSourceType:MPMovieSourceTypeFile];
   [movPlayer.view setFrame:CGRectMake(_imgVw.frame.origin.x, _imgVw.frame.origin.y, _imgVw.frame.size.width, _imgVw.frame.size.height)];
   [movPlayer prepareToPlay];
   movPlayer.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleNone;
   movPlayer.fullscreen = NO;
   movPlayer.shouldAutoplay=NO;
   [movPlayer setScalingMode:MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill];
   [self.view addSubview:movPlayer.view];


   UIButton *pauseButton=[[UIButton alloc]init];
   [pauseButton setFrame:CGRectMake(100,220, 50, 50)];
   [pauseButton setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
   [pauseButton setTag:123456789];
   [pauseButton setAccessibilityValue:@"445"];
   [pauseButton setAccessibilityLabel:@"445"];
   [pauseButton addTarget:self action:@selector(pauseBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
   [self.view addSubview:pauseButton];


}

-(void)pauseBtnClicked:(UIButton*)btn
{
    NSLog(@"clicked on pause button");

    UIButton *pause = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:123456789];

    NSLog(@"clicked on pause button");

   if ([pause.accessibilityValue intValue] == 455)
   {
       NSLog(@"Stop");
       [movPlayer stop];
       [pause setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
       [pause setAccessibilityValue:@"445"];

   }
   else if ([pause.accessibilityValue intValue] == 445)
   {
       NSLog(@"Play");

       [movPlayer play];

       [pause setBackgroundColor:[UIColor brownColor]];
       [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                               object:movPlayer];
       [pause setAccessibilityValue:@"455"];

    }
}


- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{

    NSLog(@"video playing is completed");
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = (MPMoviePlayerController*)[notification object];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                              object:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController stop];

    int pauseViewTag = 123456789;
    UIButton *pause = (UIButton*)[self.view viewWithTag:pauseViewTag];

    [pause setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];



}
```

Comment: can you guide me how to create custom progress bar?